# java - omitting special characters from text extraction

Tags: java

I have a program where I extract text or words from PDF file and insert those words to the table in database.

During insertion, I have a special regular expression to omit special characters if it exists on the word. The rule is if any words that has special characters in front of the word or at the end of the word, it gets removed.

Example:

```
Text : `,test.`
Token : `test`
Text: ?good
Token : good 
 Text: ?,.
 Token:
 Text: www.stack.com
 Token: www.stack.com
```

As long there is no space between characters, the special characters stay. This is at least how I defined it to be.

This is the general idea where I define my definition of what words to be stored. However, when it comes to certain words like underscore:

```
Text: _
Token : Same as above

Text: _—,m‘—_
Token : same as above
```

It doesn't seem to treat the underscore as a special character.

My code:

```
String lines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] words = line.split(" ");

        System.out.println("Line: " + line);



        preparedStatement = con1.prepareStatement(sql);
        int i=0;
        for (String word : words) {

            // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
            // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove
            // insert every word directly to table db
            word = word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", "");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, path1);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, word);
              System.out.println("Token: " +word);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }


    }
```

Is there a way to properly ignored every possible combination of special characters or symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of \W is `[^a-zA-Z_0-9]` (see [Java Pattern API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).

So to get the same behaviour without the underscores, replace \W with `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`

Your line of code would then be:

```
word = word.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z_0-9]+$)|(^[^a-zA-Z_0-9]+)", "");
```

Comment: Isn't \\W mean non word character such as special characters?

Comment: Correct. The docs says: \W A non-word character: [^\w] And for \w it says: A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9] See the doc.

Comment: But your answer is wrong? It should be `^[special characters symbols]`

Comment: Yes, but there are too many special character symbols. So it is easier to say not (^) normal symbol (a-zA-Z0-9)

Comment: so how does the line or code looks like now? Can you post it?

Comment: The rule is in any word, if there is any special characters/symbol at BEGINNING of the word OR End of the word, remove those speicial characters

Comment: Does `^[abc]` means the ^ refers to beginning of a line?

Comment: There is possible confusion here: ^ means beginning of line, [^a] means not the character a

Comment: I see. Then what is the `+` for and `$`?

Comment: See the docs, they don't hurt: + means one or more repetitions, $ means end of line

Comment: I mean i did read the docs, I was just confused that if I don't include the + and $ then I tested and it still gives the same results

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to replace all the special characters except space.

```
word = word.replaceAll("([ a-zA-Z0-9])", "");
```

Comment: what about my old regular expression?